# Using OnClientClick to validate if Textbox contains data and then display another row if yes

Tags: asp.net, onclientclick

i have a form in which i enter telephone numbers. i have used an image button that when pressed, it should display a new row to enter a telephone number if there was one entered in the textbox before it. however, it is not working in the way that i want it. instead it is giving the error "TelNum2 is not defined"

ASPX

```
    <tr><td class="labels">Tel. No. (XXX-XXXX) </td>
    <td class="tb">
    <asp:TextBox ID="PN1" runat="server" width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAdd1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/add.jpg" 
     Height="16px" Width="23px"  AlternateText="Add another Phone Number" 
     CausesValidation="False"  Onclick="TelNum2_Click" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" ControlToValidate="PN1" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></tr>




  <tr id="phoneNum2" runat="server"><td class="labels"> Tel. No 2. (XXX-XXXX)</td>
  <td class="tb"><asp:TextBox ID="PN2" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAdd2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/add.jpg" 
   Height="16px" Width="23px" AlternateText="Add another Phone Number" CausesValidation="False" 
   Onclick="TelNum3" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN2" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" 
   ControlToValidate="PN2" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-
   Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td></tr>

   <tr id="phoneNum3" runat="server"><td class="labels"> Tel. No 3. (XXX-XXXX)</td>
   <td class="tb"><asp:TextBox ID="PN3" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN3" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" 
    ControlToValidate="PN3" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-
    Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td></tr>
```

CS

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
        BtnNew.Visible = true;
        BtnDelete.Visible = false;    
        BtnUpdate.Visible = false;
        BtnSave.Visible = false; 
        BtnCancel.Visible = false;
        pubvar.DisableAllControls(Page);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            processAgentData.Visible = false; //area in which textboxes are displayed
            phoneNum2.Visible = false;
            phoneNum3.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            processAgentData.Visible = true;
        }


    }


   protected void TelNum2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PN1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                phoneNum2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                phoneNum2.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
    protected void TelNum3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PN2.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                phoneNum3.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                phoneNum3.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're calling "OnClientClick", it's looking for a javascript function, not a C# function. Whenever you see "Client" in events, it means javascript

Comment: can u suggest an alternative to use? it must be a property of the image button though...

Comment: If you want to use C# server-side to show the other phone number,  use the OnClick event instead, which will post-back to the server and fire the code as you describe here. If you don't want it to post back, hide the phone #2 on load with javascript, and then have javascript code to validate the text in #1, then show / hide #2 accordingly.

Comment: i changed it to onClick and it stopped throwing the error. However, when I click it, its going to my function TelNum2, however it is causing the entire page to reload instead of just making the row (phoneNum2) visible. also, on the initial page load i did hide phoneNum2.

Comment: Yes, this is the nature of postbacks in web pages. if you don't want it to refresh the page, you will want to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New2This,

Please try the following code as it should assist you:

--Should be OnClick instead of OnClientClick.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumber" runat="server" width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAdd1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/bullet.png"  
  Height="16px" Width="23px" AlternateText="Add another Phone Number"  
  CausesValidation="False" OnClick="TelNum2_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumber2" runat="server" width="120px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

--For code-behind, make sure first phone number text box has a value and if so, show the second.

```
    protected void TelNum2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PhoneNumber.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            PhoneNumber2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            PhoneNumber2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this makes sense. however, the page is still reloading and removing any fields (all textboxes - and not phone numbers - eg name, address etc) before it. Its a data entry form and i'm trying to provide another row for the user to enter another phone number everytime the they click the icon, providing of course that there is a phone number in the preceeding phone number field and so on and so on. I've updated the code to show what phoneNum2 looks like.

Comment: So you are wanting to dynamically create phone number text boxes only if the previous text box contains a phone number? Also, is there a limit on how many phone number text boxes you would like the end user to add?

Comment: yes. u got it right. users are only allowed to enter only a maximum of up to 3 phone numbers.

Comment: It seems as if your initial error has been resolved. Can you update your question with your current code? I'm interested in seeing your page_load method. Post backs are normal, however, there are ways to maintain data between post backs.

Comment: i've updated with the current code. The errors I'm receiving now are (i) its still allowing me to click the button although there is no initial phone number. (ii) upon clicking the button to add a phone number, validation immediately occurs. This shouldn't happen. It should only be on the submit button,